# Error C3493: residual' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function to solve a stream value problem as part of my Numerical methods studies. This is the 'meat' of the program yet it comes up with a number of bizarre errors, which is strange because I've used the same piece of code in other programs without any errors.

```
 void solve_stream(void)
    {
          double residual, residual_total;
        int resid_count, count=0;

        do
        {
            residual_total=0.0;
            resid_count=0;

            for(int i=0;i<maxi;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<maxj;j++)
                    if((i+j)%2==count%2)
                    {
                        residual= P[i][j]*e[i][j]-f[i][j];
                        if(i<maxi-1) residual+= P*[i+1][j]*a[i][j];
                        if(i>0) residual+= P[i-1][j]*b[i][j];
                        if(j<maxj-1) residual+= P[i][j+1]*c[i][j];
                        if(j>0) residual+= P[i][j-1]*d[i][j];

                        residual_total+= fabs(residual);
                        resid_count++;
                    }

            residual_total = residual_total/resid_count; //average residual
            count++;

            if(count%100==0) cout<<"-";
        }
        while(residual_total>1.0);
    }
```

1. On line 155, the one beginning if(i'less than' maxi-1), the compiler returns 'error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before '+' ' even though residual is defined as a double!
2. For all the variables defined it returns 'error C3493: 'residual' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified'; even for i and j!

Answer (score 1):

```
P*[i+1][j]
```

What is P? It seems to be an array but here you're multiplying it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspect:

```
P*[i+1][j]
```

You probably mean

```
P[i+1][j]
```

Comment: Thanks, you have no idea how long I've been looking at this for some subtle mistake!